# Restricting sudo commands in Ansible. Is this solution any good?

Tags: python, ansible, sudo

There is a known problem in Ansible, that it is not possible to restrict the commands that the Ansible user can run as root on hosts. This is because Ansible essentially runs python scripts via `sudo python`.

So I came up with this very simple solution: Just make a very simple wrapper, for example (although in a live system I would write it in C):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os
import sys

os.setregid(1001,1001)
os.setreuid(1001,1001)
os.environ["HOME"]="/home/byton"
os.environ["USER"]="byton"
os.system("python3 " + " ".join(sys.argv[1:]))
```

and set `ansible_python_interpreter` to this wrapper. This should force ansible to use non-root (user "bython" in this case) and then we can use sudo rules to restrict what it can run as root.

I tested it and it works, but it seems to me as too simplistic, so I wonder if you could share your comments. Especially if you think it is a bad idea (security hole? something else?)

Many thanks,

Oren